# How to use JSTL on Eclipse project?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to use JSTL

I tried to import taglib using:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

but it says cannot find tag library descriptor for

Comment: using what ? you have not written what you used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find link to download page [in jstl FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). Choose the version you need and download necessary dependencies.